# Could not access API endpoint that connects to db

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to hosting API. I built this api on .net core 6 and published it on IIS. When I try to access the endpoint that handles mssqldb it crashes.
[image]

[image]

the API endpoint that don't handle database works perfectly fine

[image]

What I tried:

1. Installed appropriate .net hosting bundle
2. Allowing SQL server in windows firewall
3. Adding TrustedConnection=true in appsettings and dev appsettings
4. Publishing with appropriate db connection string
5. Allowing everyone in folder permissions

Comment: Can you show your database connection string in your appsettings?

Comment: is it true when run with idm?can you connect to db with vs?

Comment: @CharlesHan here's my database string
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=.;Database=FinalAssessment;Trusted_Connection=True;TrustedServerCertificate=true"
 }

masoud rafiee when I run it in visual studio I can connect with db and do anything

Comment: @CapedCrusader01 you have a typo. It's supposed to be `TrustServerCertificate=true`

Comment: @akseli I renamed it and published it. It still does not work. Same error

Comment: @CapedCrusader01 are you sure that you're setting the ConnectionString in the correct AppSettings file? Check to make sure that you don't have Development and Production versions and are modifying the incorrect file. Otherwise, you can always set `Encrypt=False` which should solve the problem, but isn't really ideal in production environments.

Comment: I have never seen `server=.`. Maybe it should be `server=(local)`?